# Creating a views function that will find the single desired instance from the database and send it to the template using Django

Tags: sql, python-3.x, django

I am working on a library web app using Django. Right now a user can create as many libraries as they want and add books to the created libraries.

The user is able to choose any library and view the contents of that table on a template. I would like the user to be able to jump to another template that has the full details of any book in the database. I am passing through a request with the pk and getting errors. Do I need to add anything about the library object in here?

my views function currently for the single details:

```
def single_detail(request, pk):
    book_details = get_object_or_404(AddBook, pk=pk) 
    context = {'book_details': book_details}
    return render(request, 'library/details.html', context)
```

My function to retrieve the library in the first place and this one works:

```
def your_library(request, pk):
    lib = get_object_or_404(Library, pk=pk)  
    books = AddBook.addBook.filter(library=pk)  
    content = {'library': lib, 'books': books}
    return render(request, 'library/YourLibrary.html', content)
```

AddBook is the name of the class that determines the attributes of the entry and i didn't manually add a primary key to it since with Django you don't have to. The user is already on the page where only the contents of the chosen library are displayed.

I know my URL path needs to be this, but the whole app breaks when i have int:pk inside the details path.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.lib_home, name='homeLib'),
    path('create/', views.create_library, name='create'),
    path('add/', views.add_book, name='add'),
    path('<int:pk>/library/', views.your_library, name='libraryList'),
    path('details/<int:pk>', views.single_detail, name="singleDetail"),
]
```

HTML template that iterate through your library to show all books within, I want the last column to jump to the details page.

```
                <tr id="headerRow">
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Meta</th>
                </tr>
                {% for book in books %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="center">{{ book.book_title }}</td>
                    <td class="center">{{ book.book_author }}</td>
                    <td class="center">{{ book.genre }}</td>
                    <td class ="center"><a href="{% url 'singleDetail' %}">More Details</a></td>

                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

My models.py if this is needed:

```
class Library(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    Library = models.Manager()

    # Allows references to specific library to be returned as the owners name not the primary key

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + "'s Library"


GenreTypes = [('Spiritual', 'Spiritual'), ('Biography', 'Biography'), ('Cookbook', 'Cookbook'), ('Poetry', 'Poetry'), ('Self-Help', 'Self-Help'), ('Sci-Fi', 'Sci-Fi'), ('Learning', 'Learning')]


    class AddBook(models.Model):
        library = models.ForeignKey(Library, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        book_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        book_author = models.CharField(max_length=250,)
        genre = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=GenreTypes)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
        addBook = models.Manager()
```

Comment: What error did you get? Share your traceback and part of html where you add singleDetail.

Comment: TypeError: single_detail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Answer (score 0):

`singleDetail` requires an argument `pk`.

So add `book.pk` to `singleDetail` url in the following line:

```
<td class ="center"><a href="{% url 'singleDetail' book.pk %}">More Details</a></td>
```